# Returning rows where various combinations of nulls may exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure

I'm looking for the best way to extract records which meet various criteria, as one result set. I'm using SQL Azure.

In a slightly simplified example, here's my scenario (I've attached a diagram of this part of the schema to help clarify!):

I have students attendance records in tblCourseStudents. One column is SponsorID - this is ID of the person who "sponsored" that person for the course - typically, but not always, their manager. This is a foreign key, related to PersonID in tblPeople. In many cases, however, this column is null, as the company hasn't historically always recorded that information.

In tblPeople, there's a CompanyID column, which identifies which company any person works for. There's also a column called  IsPrimary (BIT) which will be set to 1 for the person identified as the primary contact for that company. It's possible that there's no-one at the company set to primary, but there's never more than one such person.

I'd like to run a query which shows the following:

1. The Student Details, including
2. The name and email of their sponsor, if the sponsorID is NOT null (as
   "Sponsor"), OR if this IS null
3. The name and email of the person at
   the student's company marked as IsPrimary = True, where such a
   person exists, OR
4. The student details with NULL for the "Sponsor"
   details where neither of the above exists.

Can anyone help? I've been staring at the screen for long enough now.

Here's that schema:
[image: Schema for the relevant portion of the database]

Comment: This looks an awful lot like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm flattered! Haven't done any homework for about 25 years!!! I've been looking at the idea of using CASE WHEN SponsorID IS NULL THEN tblPeople.PersonID - but can't figure out the way in which to specify an additional check so that the WHEN clause only returns the PersonID where they are in the same company and they are set to IsPrimary=1. I also considered using a view which would return the ID of all people in one col (in order to show sponsors) and of primary contacts in another, and using ISNULL() in the join, but I read that this is extremely inefficient (which I can well imagine.

Comment: regardless of your age... you still haven't answer his most important question? "What have you tried?"

Comment: <sigh> I was TRYING to explain what I'd tried, but didn't realise that hitting Enter would not insert a line break but would post my reponse... The squared graph-paper is not a sign of a homework book (do such things still exist?), incidentally, but of my using Papyrus on my tablet, as I do for all database designs!

Comment: Certainly the combination of graph paper and the names of the tables make it look like homework. Also, the tbl prefix is something we see a lot in homework and not so much in the real world.

Comment: True enough. But the use of Hungarian notation is something that I was taught many moons ago when I was first learning how to build databases, and is habit that I've never got out of. 
And the table names are a real simplification of what I'm actually dealing with, because I didn't want to have to ask people to wade through the 6 or so tables that are actually involved.
The project is actually for a company that trains air crew et al on things like carriage of dangerous goods by air certification, which is why the tables are full of things like "Students" and "Courses".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, no CASE statements required.

```
SELECT stud.Name, stud.Email,
     coalesce(sponsor.Name,'') SponsorName, coalesce(sponsor.Email,'') SponsorEmail
FROM tblCourseStudents cs
INNER JOIN tblPeople stud on stud.ID = cs.StudentID
LEFT JOIN tblPeople prime ON prime.CompanyID = stud.CompanyID AND prime.IsPrimary = 1
LEFT JOIN tblPeople sponsor on sponsor.ID = COALESCE(cs.SponsorID, prime.ID)
```

You might be able to improve on this a bit further to replace two of the JOINs to tblPeople with one APPLY operator.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help with this - that's brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
select 
S.*,
CASE 
    WHEN Sponsor.PersonID is not null or (Sponsor.PersonID is null and Contact.PersonID is null) 
    THEN Sponsor.fname +' '+Sponsor.lname ELSE Contact.fname +' '+Contact.lname 
END as Name,
CASE 
    WHEN Sponsor.PersonID is not null or (Sponsor.PersonID is null and Contact.PersonID is null) 
    THEN Sponsor.email ELSE Contact.email 
END as Email

from tblCourseStudents S 
    left join tblPeople Sponsor 
         on Sponsor.personID=S.SponsorID 
    left join tblPeople StudentCompany 
         on StudentCompany.personID=S.StudentID 
    left join tblPeople Contact 
         on Contact.CompanyID=StudentCompany.CompanyID 
         and Contact.IsPrimary=1
```

Comment: That's great - thanks for the answer... Just trying it now (having to do some tweaking as I simplified the structure somewhat for the posting) and will let you know how I get on.  Thanks again.